# Build my application, create an executable and a setup program

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I created a WPF C# application and using entity framework to connect to an SQL database, and read write data to it.

My application have multiple library projects and the main project that contains the UI.

I want to build the application in order to sell it. I want to have something similar to a normal application, where you have a main exe executable and .dll diles that represent the other projects and libraries used.

I also need to have a setup file that will setup the application as normal applications do.

1. How can I do that?
2. Will I have to do something with the SQL database in order to build with the project or that is done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have VS2010 you can use VS2010 based "Setup and Deployment" project template to create a Setup project and chose any of the given type i.e. CAB with Setup.exe or MSI or web Deployment which is suitable for your distribution. The UI is as below:

[image]

You can also try 3 party Installation project i.e. InstallShield etc also.

For SQL DB there are separate ways to distribute the database. If you have SQL Express or SQL CE then you can package it and ship with main project as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb264562%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). However for SQL Server, you just need to create a database deployment script and documentation about your data base first and then package it with main distribution. Or it can be done separately.